# Not able to stub post method of android.os.Handler class

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am using `Junit4` and `Mockito` for writing my test cases. In one of the classes which is under test, there is a function `init()`, which gets called from the constructor.

```
void init(){
//Some code 
  Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        //Some code
      }
    });
}
```

The following exception is thrown when trying to create `constructor` of that class.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method post in android.os.Handler not mocked.
```

Then I tried to  mock `post` method of the `Handler` class using the following code

```
Handler handler = spy(new Handler());
when(handler.post(Matchers.any(Runnable.class))).thenReturn(true);
```

But still I keep on getting the same `exception`. What should I do to stub the post method of the Handler class ?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing more of your context, but I see two options.

First, if you have the ability, you can avoid using `new` for something you are going to need to mock.  You can either inject it in the constructor, or inject a factory in the constructor and mock the factory so you get mock `Handler`'s from it.  For most cases, something along those lines is the preferred approach.

If that is not practical, you can use [PowerMock to construct new objects](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage#how-to-mock-construction-of-new-objects).

Use PowerMockito.whenNew, e.g.

```
Handler handler = spy(new Handler());
when(handler.post(Matchers.any(Runnable.class))).thenReturn(true);
whenNew(Handler.class).withExpectedArguments(looper).thenReturn(handler);
```

That code is not tested, but should basically work.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in interpreting "Method not mocked": You are using [a no-implementation version of the Android system library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36587569/1426891), so you need to use mocking here, or you'll need to switch to a library like [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) that has Java implementations of classes like `Handler` for testing.

**You will need `doReturn` for your stub.** One of the interesting unintended aspects of `when` syntax is that it actually calls the method it's stubbing:

```
when(handler.post(Matchers.any(Runnable.class))).thenReturn(true);
//   calls
//   handler.post(            null            )
```

And, because spies call the real method by default, you'll actually invoke the problematic method while trying to stub it. Instead, use `doReturn` to tell Mockito to temporarily deactivate the stub.

```
doReturn(true).when(handler).post(Matchers.any(Runnable.class));
```

**You'll need to inject the stub into your test.** This is a little tricky because you're doing "heavy lifting" in the constructor; you lose out on a post-construction opportunity to swap out your handler. [jhericks mentions a PowerMock solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37261226/1426891), though I recommend refactoring so you don't do so much on construction, and as a third option you could work around this with a testing overload:

```
public class YourClass {
  /** Public constructor for external access. */
  public YourClass() {
    this(new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()));
  }

  /** Package-private constructor for testing. */
  YourClass(Handler handler) {
    init(handler);
  }

  private void init(Handler handler) {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        //Some code
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Side note: Be extra careful that `init` is private or final, because [it's dangerous to call overridable methods from constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3404301/1426891).

Answer (score 0):

try to execute the runnable code block

```
val handler: Handler = mock(Handler::class.java)

`when`(handler.post(any(Runnable::class.java))).thenAnswer {
       (it.arguments[0] as? Runnable)?.run()
       true
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Got the same error(**java.lang.RuntimeException: Method postDelayed in android.os.Handler not mocked**), and ended up to resolve the issue by **passing the handler into the class constructor** and don't even need to stub it anymore.

Sample test class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class MainViewModelImplTest {

    @Mock
    lateinit var handler: Handler

    lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        mainViewModel = MainViewModelImpl(handler = handler)
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
    }

    @Test
    fun testDoStuff() {
        mainViewModel.doStuff()

        //verifty...
        //assert...
    }

}
```

The sample class to be tested

```
class MainViewModelImpl
@Inject constructor(
    val handler: Handler
): ViewModel() {
    private val task = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            // do things
            handler.postDelayed(this, 60 * 1000)
        }
    }

    fun doStuff() {
        task.run()
    }
}
```